# Moving iTunes Library with an external hard disk

Tags: itunes

my problem is not the typical iTunes import/export scenario since all my files are already on an external hard disk.
I am planing to buy a new Mac and plugging the disk to the new machine would not be a big deal but I am looking for a way to keep all the "Metadata" like ratings and playlists.

As I already found out the ratings are not saved in the songs and get lost when you move files around and I guess so will the playlists.

So how can I add all my songs the a completely new Mac and still keep the ratings? (Playlists are less important)

Answer (score 2):

iTunes has a number of files pertaining to the information you wish to keep, and they are stored in your iTunes folder. They are:

- iTunes Library.itl
- iTunes Music Library.xml
- iTunes Library Genius.itdb
- iTunes Library Extras.itdb

Make sure these are moved over with your collection. Spotlight will help you locate these files if you're having any trouble.

This article is very useful if you require further information:
http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/the-complete-guide-to-backing-up-your-itunes-library/

Comment: I also find it helps if you set your itunes files location preference BEFORE copying your old database. iTunes will find your files right away when loading it for the first time, preventing any file not found errors.